# WooCommerce, Apply discount coupon to fee also

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have added fee to WooCommerce cart using  `$woocommerce->cart->add_fee()` method.

When applying a WooCommerce coupon code with a percentage discount, it doesn't consider the fee amount while calculating the discount.

Eg:

```
Product Price: 15
Additional Fee: 5
Discount: 10%=> 1.5 (10% of 15)
Total: 21.5
```

But we need it as

```
Product Price: 15
Additional Fee: 5
Discount: 10%=> 2 ( 10% of 15+5)
Total: 22
```

Can't find any hooks or so to include the fee in the discount calculation process

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook on calculate_fee and modify accordingly

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_custom_surcharge', 10, 1 );
function wc_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE set your percent rate
    $percent = 1; // 1%

    // Fee calculation
    $fee = ( $cart->subtotal - $cart->get_cart_discount_total() ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee if it is bigger than O
    if( $fee > 0 )
        $cart->add_fee( __('Surcharge', 'woocommerce'), $fee, true );
}
```